# My App Does Not Install

Tags: apk, unsigned

OK, I am making an app for a school project. The app works on the emulator on multiple screens and platforms. The problem is, I can't quite figure out how to export it as an apk but signed. so I export it as an unsigned apk and try to install it on my rooted android device. Yes I have the thing where it says install non market applications checked for on so it should work. all it does is start installing and then says application not installed.

Any hints as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some documentation on app signing for final release, it is a bit of hassle but will get through it. http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html